# Can these fanciful lizardfolk shoulders properly fit together?

Tags: anatomy, humanoid

One unique way of making a reptilian humanoid is a rather fanciful joint in which human-like shoulders, including the extension of the shoulderblade, are seemingly stapled to the sides of the ventral face of the chest. Such an anatomy is seen, for example, in the lizalfos from LOZ:BOTW

[image: A botw Lizalfo]

There is an issue with this design, that being the internal anatomy of this structure: Unlike the human form, a normal shoulderblade would intersect through the ribs, which is not possible. There also seems to be issues with the muscles. While we could reinvent everything, that is a bit of a cop-out here

Could these shoulders be made to fit together within the set of bones and muscles in the tetrapods?

Comment: To me this looks like the neck is a bit longer and thicker than we're used to, while the ribcage and shoulder bones are where they are supposed to go.

Comment: @KeizerHarm This question is about the shoulders

Comment: I am saying that, in your reference picture, I don't see a meaningful change from humanoid in the skeletal anatomy. I don't see "shoulders stapled to the sides of the lower chest", I see a hunchbacked creature where the whole horizontal part of the upper spine is neck, not ribcage, and the shoulders are where they're supposed to go.

Comment: @KeizerHarm The human shoulder is quite close to the back (within the confines of human body depth), whereas the shoulder described here is closer to the belly side

Comment: @IchtysKing look up references of chameleon skeletons. Or of the T-Rex for an even more extreme case of arms on the ventral side.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Chameleons and T. rex don't have very humanoid shoulders

Comment: @IchtysKing then really my answer would be that the maker drawing took artistic license, that anatomically realistic front-facing shoulders don't look like that. I'm not sure what need in your story only that exact type of shoulder can fulfill, but I don't think I can help you justify it. Perhaps someone else can.

Comment: There does not appear to be anything wrong with the anatomy, just don't try to use Humans as reference, humans are extremely derived creatures, human's unusual anatomy is not a a good reference for most non-human things.

Comment: Only problem I see with this guy is he might be very front-heavy, especially with that spear.  You might consider making the tail longer or thicker to provide a counterbalance.  Larger feet (especially towards the front) would also help keep this thing upright.  Also thicker legs, bent towards the front, to provide more support below the center of mass.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between "a cop-out here…" and how those shoulders might be made to fit together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Second elbow

The creature you refer to looks like a 90s alien with an easy skeleton to animate for games. Another issue that strikes me is the 360 degrees freedom of that shoulder! These beasts you only find in games..

[image]

https://www.google.com/search?q=lizalfos&tbm=isch

Consider a second elbow, like in arthropods. The "upper upper" arm can be firmly attached to a narrower humanoid shoulder, which need not be too prominent. Together, the two elbows will provide angular freedom the lizalfos got used to. The upper elbow gives xz-freedom, the lower elbow handles yz-freedom. Less bone mass and muscle is required to support the shoulder, muscle is in the upper arms around the elbows. The shoulder can be less prominent, but still has to carry the mass.. this creature has huge arms, when the musculature would be complete !

Comment: The question clearly states to stay within normal tetrapod anatomy. How is this achieved here?

Comment: @IchthysKing if you want a normal tetrapod, the shoulders should be placed more forward. But that answer is trivial. This beast has a shoulder circular bearing halfway the ribs. No tetrapod has that because there is no mount on the side of the ribs. The animal as shown in Google Images (most variants) seems bipedal (yours is bipedal ? ) think of weaker, lighter arms ?

Answer (score 16):

### Your anatomy is fine

There is nothing impossible about your creatures shoulder anatomy.

The human shoulder joint is very unusual - using it a reference is just going to throw you off. Looking at most animals, the shoulder blade is vertical on the side of the body. Apes in general have derived shoulders evolved for a particular type of climbing. As apes we also have chest cavities that are wider than they are tall which is also weird - most animals have a narrow but deep chest.

A few things your anatomy tells us

1. The shoulder joint of your creature is not very muscular meaning it is not very strong. Which kind of makes sense - if it had anymore mass in the front half of its body it would fall over.
2. It probably can't raise its hands far over its head, or if it can, its arms can go back further than vertical.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**The Spine is Not Where You Think**

<s>If I understand correctly the problem is arms and legs are usually anchored to the spine.</s> But how can that be if the spine is located here?

[image]

The solution is to have the spine here instead:

[image]

Comment: forelimbs are not anchored to the spine, not in any vertebrate. that is why you can shrug your shoulders.

Comment: @John Of course you are right. Just me being a silly sausage (as usual).

Answer (score 2):

**Flamingo Knees**

[image]

What look like shoulders are actually elbows. The real shoulders are embedded inside the body. The *forearm* is made of extended and fused metacarpals. The *hand* is made of phalanges.

Answer (score 2):

**Your lizard has a thoracic kyphosis.**

[image: kyphosis]

[image: kyphosis]

https://www.chortho.com/specialties/kyphosis

The shoulders are in the same place as normal.  Because the spine curves back it seems like the shoulders are too far forward.  Really the back is farther back.   The spine is curved and so the front to back (anterior - posterior) excursion of the thorax is greater.